I can not load webpage in ASP.NET & React demo project
I am new in ASP.NET. So I used this guide. Deploy working fine. but I can not load any webpage
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-react?view=vs-2022
Who can help me?
I would load react front end with asp.net.
I don't have any bug and any issue.
When open the project in browser, browser display 404 error.
What is mistake?

We just need to publish the ReactApp1.Server project. Here is the basic steps for brand new project.


Double-click the project_name.exe file, and the applciation will start with 5000 port.

TroubleShoot Steps
1. Access the api endpoint(http://localhost:5000/WeatherForecast), make sure the asp.net-core-webapi application is working well.

2. Make sure there are app.UseStaticFiles(); and app.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html"); in your Program.cs file.

3. Please noted, we can't open SwaggerUI in development environment, unless we change the environment.

